# Quotient of two ideals, considered as a fractional ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noetherian

Let $R$ be an integrally closed Noetherian domain and $K$ be its field of fractions. Consider two ideals  $M, I \in R$ such that $I \subset M$ and $M$ is maximal ideal in $R$.

Is it true, that if a quotient $I:M$ considered as a quotient of two fractional ideals (and therefore a fractional ideal in itself) is unequal to $I$, then the same quotient considered as a quotient of two ideals from $R$ is also unequal to $I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $R$ Noetherian and integrally closed implies that $R$ is completely integrally closed, i.e. $(J :_K J) = R$ for every ideal $J$.  (This follows because when $k \in K$ is such that $kJ \subseteq J$ for a finitely generated ideal $J$, $k$ is integral over $R$).

> **Trivial Fact:** Let $R$ be a completely integrally closed domain with quotient field $K$.  Let $I \subseteq J$ ideals.  Then $(I :_R J) = (I :_K J)$.

This settles your question affirmatively.

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thanks!